# Problems with deleting old records from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Each time a php script runs i want to delete old entries by `id`. But MySQL throws me this error:

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

This is the query:

```
DELETE FROM am_shoutbox WHERE MAX(msg_id)-160 > msg_id
```

What is the problem here? I tried around and solved it by selecting the highest `id` to php first and then delete with a second query, but for better performance i want to do this in one if possible.

I hope someone can figure out what is wrong with the query above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use aggregate functions in the `WHERE` clause. You can try something like this (using subquery that is retrieving `MAX(msg_id)`) :

```
 DELETE FROM am_shoutbox 
 WHERE ( SELECT * 
         FROM ( SELECT MAX(msg_id) 
                FROM am_shoutbox ) m ) - 160 > msg_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried your query but i get another error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'am_shoutbox' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

The invalid use of group function the error describes is due use of `MAX(msg_id)` in `WHERE` clause.      You can use it either in a select/subselect or in the `HAVING` clause:

```
    delete from am_shoutbox 
    where 
    (select (max(ams.msg_id) FROM am_shoutbox ams) - 160) > msg_id
```

*you may need to specify a table alias in the sub-query as above

or the more elegant and better performance way:

```
    delete from am_shoutbox 
    having (max(msg_id) - 160) > msg_id
```

Comment: The method with HAVING throws this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'having (max(msg_id) - 160) > msg_id' at line 1. The other method with WHERE throws this error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM am_shoutbox.msg_id) - 160) > msg_id' at line 3